# Linux kernel module blocking entire Linux

Tags: linux, module, kernel

I wrote my the first simple Linux module for Led flashing. If I use for pause between Led ON and Led Off the command ssleep(1) then everything is okay but if I use udelay(40) then entire Linux and applications such as SSH, Webserver etc are frozen. Could you help me why it happens and how fix it ?

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/gpio.h>
#include <mach/gpio.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static int led_on_init(void)
{

    gpio_direction_output(AT91_PIN_PA24, 0);
    int i = 1;
    while (i == 1)
    {
        gpio_set_value(AT91_PIN_PA24, 1);
        /*udelay(40);*/
        ssleep(1);
        gpio_set_value(AT91_PIN_PA24, 0);
        ssleep(1);
       /*udelay(40);*/
    }
}
    static void led_on_exit(void)
    {
        gpio_set_value(AT91_PIN_PA24, 0);
    }


module_init(led_on_init);
module_exit(led_on_exit);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`udelay` is a busy-waiting function while `sleep` will schedule the current task out(to run other tasks) and go back when the time is up.

So if your kernel is not configured as preemptible one, the cpu which is running `udelay` won't have chance to be scheduled. If your machine only has 1 cpu, the entire machine will be blocked.

In your circumstance, it's recommended to use `sleep` instead of `udelay`.

Comment: Thank you. I am allowed preemptible kernel. Now it working.